# Parse URL and get response to give location header back

Tags: php, parsing

Am new to PHP and still in my initial stages. I need to complete an operation.

The function accepts a parameter URL and should append a token (already available) to the URL, then the URL will have to parse the response to give the Location header back to the client.

Here is the function

```
<?php    
  function authenticate($url) {
    echo $token; 
    //perform the operation
    return $url; // after appending the token to url and performing the operation.
  }
?>
```

Comment: you can append simply like `return $url.$token;` for parsing, explain everything in details

Comment: If accessing a variable that is defined outside the function, you will need to add `global $token;` before your echo, inside the function.